# Flink HA Cluster JobManager issues

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a setup with flink 1.2 cluster, made up of 3 JobManagers and 2 TaskManagers. I start the Zookeeper Quorum from JobManager1, I get confirmation Zookeeper starts on the other 2 JobManagers then I start a Flink job on this JobManager1.

The flink-conf.yaml is the same on all 5 VMs this means jobmanager.rpc.address: points to JobManager1 everywhere.

If I turn off the VM running JobManager1 I would expect Zookeeper to say one of the remaining JobManagers is the leader and the TaskManagers should reconnect to it. Instead I get in the TaskManagers' logs a lot of these messages

```
2017-03-14 14:13:21,827 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:43660/user/jobmanager (attempt 11, timeout: 30 seconds)
2017-03-14 14:13:21,836 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:43660] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:43660]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:43660]
```

I modified the original IP to 1.2.3.4 for confidentiality and because it's always the same IP (of JobManager1).

More logs:

```
2017-03-15 10:28:28,655 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for Async calls on Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/1)
2017-03-15 10:28:38,534 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
2017-03-15 10:28:46,606 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:28:52,431 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:29:02,435 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:29:10,489 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager akka://flink/user/taskmanager disconnects from JobManager akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779/user/jobmanager: Old JobManager lost its leadership.
2017-03-15 10:29:10,490 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Cancelling all computations and discarding all cached data.
2017-03-15 10:29:10,491 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Attempting to fail task externally Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/1) (75fd495cc6acfd72fbe957e60e513223).
2017-03-15 10:29:10,491 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/1) (75fd495cc6acfd72fbe957e60e513223) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.Exception: TaskManager akka://flink/user/taskmanager disconnects from JobManager akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779/user/jobmanager: Old JobManager lost its leadership.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.handleJobManagerDisconnect(TaskManager.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$taskmanager$TaskManager$$handleJobManagerLeaderAddress(TaskManager.scala:1426)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(TaskManager.scala:286)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:44)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.aroundReceive(TaskManager.scala:122)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
2017-03-15 10:29:10,512 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Triggering cancellation of task code Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/1) (75fd495cc6acfd72fbe957e60e513223).
2017-03-15 10:29:10,515 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Attempting to fail task externally Flat Map (1/1) (dd555e0437867c3180a1ecaf0a9f4d04).
2017-03-15 10:29:10,515 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Flat Map (1/1) (dd555e0437867c3180a1ecaf0a9f4d04) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.Exception: TaskManager akka://flink/user/taskmanager disconnects from JobManager akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779/user/jobmanager: Old JobManager lost its leadership.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.handleJobManagerDisconnect(TaskManager.scala:1074)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$taskmanager$TaskManager$$handleJobManagerLeaderAddress(TaskManager.scala:1426)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(TaskManager.scala:286)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:44)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager.aroundReceive(TaskManager.scala:122)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
2017-03-15 10:29:10,516 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Triggering cancellation of task code Flat Map (1/1) (dd555e0437867c3180a1ecaf0a9f4d04).
2017-03-15 10:29:10,516 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Disassociating from JobManager
2017-03-15 10:29:10,525 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Shutting down BlobCache
2017-03-15 10:29:10,542 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:29:10,546 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/1) (75fd495cc6acfd72fbe957e60e513223).
2017-03-15 10:29:10,548 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Flat Map (1/1) (dd555e0437867c3180a1ecaf0a9f4d04).
2017-03-15 10:29:10,551 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for Flat Map (1/1)
2017-03-15 10:29:10,552 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.5:43893/user/jobmanager (attempt 1, timeout: 500 milliseconds)
2017-03-15 10:29:10,567 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for Source: Custom Source -> Flat Map (1/1)
2017-03-15 10:29:10,632 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Successful registration at JobManager (akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.5:43893/user/jobmanager), starting network stack and library cache.
2017-03-15 10:29:10,633 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Determined BLOB server address to be /1.2.3.5:42830. Starting BLOB cache.
2017-03-15 10:29:10,633 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobCache                       - Created BLOB cache storage directory /tmp/blobStore-d97e08db-d2f1-4f00-a7d1-30c2f5823934
2017-03-15 10:29:15,551 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:29:20,571 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:29:25,582 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
2017-03-15 10:29:30,592 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@1.2.3.4:44779]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /1.2.3.4:44779]
```

Does anyone know why the TaskManagers are not trying to reconnect to one of the remaining JobManagers (like 1.2.3.5 above)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed instructions in this link: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/jobmanager_high_availability.html to start the cluster in HA mode?

Comment: Hi Dawid, yes the issue seems to be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793598/flink-1-2-does-not-start-in-ha-cluster-mode.

Comment: Actually I have even created PR fixing it ;) Will try to speak up to merge it sooner. Until it will be merged just remove the `else` branch of first inner `if`.  You can have a look at the PR here: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3506

Comment: Anyway could you close one of those two questions? Let's not pollute SO ;)

Comment: I added the change to the shell script, cluster starts in HA mode but I get the same behaviour TaskManagers keep connecting to the killed JobManager instead of available ones.

Comment: Opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6063 for this.

Comment: I responded in the issue. I think everything is working just fine, and just the logs are maybe a bit misleading. Try to use the cluster before and after killing JM and you will see everything is ok.

Comment: It could be misleading but more importantly the job is not resumed, which is why I needed HA for.

Comment: HA in this case stands for availability of a cluster. For a JOB to be restarted after such a failure you can add `RestartStrategy`: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/restart_strategies.html#restart-strategies-1

Comment: I have this in the code   env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(50, // number
                  // of
                  // restart
                  // attempts
    Time.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // delay
  )); and if I kill one of the TaskManagers it will resume on another available one

Comment: Could you post some minimal code example that fails to restart the job in this scenario somewhere? Of course without any confidential data, as I am unable to recreate this behaviour, with a simple job I run everything seems restarted correctly. My logs looks very similar to yours.

Comment: Sure, check Jira please

Comment: Ok, so first of all the provided code is not a "running" example, but anyway tried to run it using kafka, all you environment configuration and the job restarts smoothly. Without FULL logs from all your TaskManagers and JobManagers I don't think will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone facing the same issue, HA requires you to provide a DFS location accessible from all nodes. I had backend state checkpoint directory and zookeeper storage directory pointing on each VM to a local filesystem location and when one of the JobManagers went down the new leader couldn't resume the running jobs because of lack of information / location not accessible.

Edit: Since this was asked, the file I modified (In the case of Apache Flink 1.2 (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/config.html)) was

```
conf/flink-conf.yaml
```

I set

```
state.backend.fs.checkpointdir
high-availability.zookeeper.storageDir
```

to AWS S3 paths .accessible from both TaskManagers and JobManagers.

Comment: Which files did you proceed to edit to resolve this issue?

Comment: conf/flink-conf.yaml (check https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/config.html)

Comment: How did you proceed to modify the file, in particular? It could really help if you could consider to extend your current answer with these additional informations.